# Should jpegtran remove more bytes than mogrify strip?

Tags: linux, images, imagemagick

I'm currently using `mogrify -strip image.jpg` to remove unwanted bytes from images, it was suggested I could remove further data by using `jpegran` from `libjpeg`, something like:

```
jpegtran -copy none -optimize -outfile image.jpg image.jpg
```

The problem I'm having – if it even is a problem – is that `jpegtran` doesn't seem to actually do anything that mogrify isn't already doing. In all my testing the filesize just stays the same. If I remove the mogrify part of my code and replace with `jpegtran` then it seems to perform the same function.

For example:

- image without compression: 300k
- image with `mogrify -strip` + `jpegtran`: 272k
- image with `mogrify -strip` only: 272k
- image with `jpegtran` only: 272k

I was under the impression though that `mogrify` just removed image profiles/comments and that `jpegtran` did this as well as losslessly compressing the image to make it smaller. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg) that `jpegtran` "optimizes the Huffman coding layer", strips extra application specific data (what `mogrify -strip` does), and converts between progressive and non-progressive jpeg formats.  It also has the ability to crop, rotate/flip, and convert to grayscale without decompressing and recompressing the image.

I presume that if the Huffman coding layer is already at it's optimum state, jpegtran can't do any better.

Comment: i would assume that too, but it seems unlikely given i've tried images from various sources (digital camera/iPhone/web) and found the results to be the same

Comment: confirmed here http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php "By default we compute optimal Huffman coding tables"